# methodMissing no longer being called on extension after upgrading to Gradle 2.2

Tags: gradle

Our build uses a custom plugin extension in gradle that has dynamic methods. This worked fine in gradle 2.1, but methodMissing is no longer called in 2.2 and I get the following exception (here's the caused by part):

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method common() for arguments [api] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultComponentModuleMetadataHandler_Decorated@1bef1304.
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:172)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultComponentModuleMetadataHandler_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
...
```

How do I get dynamic functions working in our build system with gradle 2.2?

The Background:

These dynamic methods are used for several things, but one is to simplify how projects depend on other projects (it is a very large system with over 80 subprojects that each may have multiple named APIs (public, internal, add-on, etc)).

This is my Plugin's apply:

```
void apply(Project project) {
   project.subprojects.each { subproject ->
      subproject.extensions.create("modules", ModuleExtension.class ) }
}
```

ModuleExtension has no variables or functions other than methodMissing:

```
def methodMissing(String name, args)
{
    //return project dependency based on name/args. This no longer gets called in 2.2!
}
```

Sample usage in a gradle file:

```
dependencies {
   compile module.nameOfModule( "name of api" )
}
```

I've also overrode the following in ModuleExtension just to see if they are getting called, but they are not:

```
def invokeMethod(String name, args)
def propertyMissing(String name)
def propertyMissing(String name, value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually unable to reproduce this issue in Gradle 2.2. However, this is a somewhat misuse of Gradle extensions. If you simply want a globally available object I would simply add it as a project extra property. This has the added benefit of not having to be created for every subproject, since projects inherit properties from their parent.

```
ext {
    modules = new ModuleExtension()
}
```

**Edit:** This is due to the new support for [module replacements](http://gradle.org/docs/2.2/release-notes#declaring-module-replacements) introduced in Gradle 2.2. The symbol `modules` within a `dependencies` block now delegates to a `ComponentModuleMetadataHandler` rather than your extension. You'll either have to rename your extension something other than `modules` or qualify the call by using `project.modules.nameOfModule`.

Comment: My understanding is this is exactly what extensions are for. I'm not looking for just a global object, I'm trying to make a simpler DSL for my project. I'm using this in several other ways that are perhaps better examples. This is just where it dies first.

Comment: Also, In this forum thread, Gradle seems to explicitly state this is a valid use case: [link](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/add_dynamic_convention_properties_from_a_plugin)

Comment: Understood. It wasn't clear if your extension provided a configuration DSL as well. If that is the case then yes, you are correct, and extension is a good fit. Like I said, I was able to create an extension using Gradle 2.2 in a local test. I didn't however try via a Plugin, or to a multi-project build.

Comment: I can create the extension. It's when I try to reference it in the gradle file where it fails. It never calls methodMissing in 2.2, but did in 2.1.

Comment: I've updated my answer. This is caused by the addition of the new module replacements feature of Gradle 2.2.

Comment: Wow. That was it. I've been pulling my hair out, digging through gradle's code trying to find out why it was no longer working. Thank you!